# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in KeywordsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, openssl

I don't know what's going on here. I've been running this controller method for days, and now all of a sudden I'm getting this oppenssl  error, and I haven't made any changes that I can imagine being the cause for this.  My application makes call to an external SOAP api, and I have notice this error all of a sudden is being displayed only with actions that interact with said API. Is it possible that recent changes made on the other side of this API are causing this? What does it all mean? Here is my source and the error stack:

KeywordsController#index

```
def index
    user = User.find session[:user_id]
    user = user.as_json
    @keywords = Keyword.get_keywords(user)
    @keywords = @keywords.to_array(:get_response, :return, :data, :item)

end
```

Error trace:

```
    /home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
httpi (1.1.1) lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:75:in `do_request'
httpi (1.1.1) lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:22:in `get'
httpi (1.1.1) lib/httpi.rb:86:in `block in get'
httpi (1.1.1) lib/httpi.rb:193:in `with_adapter'
httpi (1.1.1) lib/httpi.rb:84:in `get'
savon (1.1.0) lib/savon/wasabi/document.rb:34:in `resolve_document'
savon (1.1.0) lib/savon/wasabi/document.rb:15:in `xml'
wasabi (2.5.0) lib/wasabi/document.rb:131:in `parse'
wasabi (2.5.0) lib/wasabi/document.rb:118:in `parser'
wasabi (2.5.0) lib/wasabi/document.rb:34:in `endpoint'
savon (1.1.0) lib/savon/client.rb:114:in `preconfigure'
savon (1.1.0) lib/savon/client.rb:80:in `request'
app/models/keyword.rb:15:in `get_keywords'
app/controllers/keywords_controller.rb:7:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__37600477__process_action__984091946__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__633773016__call__27066224__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/edu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Local Server logs:

```
    HTTPI executes HTTP GET using the net_http adapter


Started GET "/keywords" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-19 17:44:45 -0500
Processing by KeywordsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 621ms

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
  app/models/keyword.rb:15:in `get_keywords'
  app/controllers/keywords_controller.rb:7:in `index'


  Rendered /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (30.2ms)
  Rendered /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (13.1ms)
  Rendered /home/edu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (95.3ms)
```

Comment: Can you connect and query the API outside of your application? It seems like it could definitely be caused by a change with the API and/or its server.

Comment: Yea, I'm using SOAP UI to try out different api calls, and the exact same calls are working in there.

Comment: You said you made changes, but don't think they would cause it. Can you revert those changes and check just to be 100% sure?

Comment: Yea, I'll try to revert my changes. Also, I just edited the post to show what happens when my browser hits that my index route.  It looks like its not getting to the other server before it returns the error, or am I not reading this right.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the exact same issue 9 years later....